# Binding Datagrid Item to Textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I try to bind a selected item in my datagrid to some textboxes.
Sadly the textboxes wont be updated on change.

If you need more Informations fell free to ask.

In my view i try to bind the the data of the selected Item of the Datagrid to the Textboxes.
in the Textboxes there can be a new employee you want to add or one of the Datagrid that you want to edit.

```
    <TextBox Name="TxtName" Text="{Binding Employee.LastName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="TxtFirstName" Text="{Binding Employee.FirstName}"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="TxtDateOfBirth" Text="{Binding Employee.DateOfBirth, StringFormat=d}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
    <ComboBox Name="CmbGender" SelectedItem="{Binding Employee.Gender}" ItemsSource="{Binding Genders}" DisplayMemberPath="Short" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>


    <DataGrid Name="GrdAllEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

In my ViewModel i set the Value of the Selected Employee to the Employee that is shown in the Textboxes and raise the Events for both.

```
        public Employee SelectedEmployee
        {
            get { return _selectedEmployee; }
            set
            {
                _selectedEmployee = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
                _employee = _selectedEmployee;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Employee");
            }
        }
```

After this the values are correct on debugging. but the view will not be updated.

Comment: So `SelectedEmployee` setter is triggered when you change selected item in `DataGrid`?

Comment: A good way to improve your question and have people read it (it might actually help you solve the problem yourself) is to remove as much code as you can until removing more code would not reproduce the problem and only then, post it.

Comment: @Boot750 also make sure which value is set as at the moment you bind `SelectedEmployee`, which updates `Employee` property, and also trigger `SelectionChanged` command which also does `Employee = _selectedEmployee;`

Comment: @dkozl 1. Yes the SelecteEmplyee trigger is triggered if when i change the selection.
2. Both parts set the same value, so im able to remove one of those. For now i removed in the SelectionChange methode. The Values are right in the class. But it wont update the Textbox. Thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: @franssu im sorry, ill do it better next time

Comment: *ill do it better next time*... why wait? You can edit your question and *do it better* this time. Also, we generally like words on this website too. They're great for describing problems in detail... you should try using some.

Comment: @Boot750 I've just tried you code, without commands, and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me after i replaced my own classes for the RelayCommand and ViewModelBase with the ones of MVVMlight, that i downloaded from nuget.

https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

I just had to change the NotifyPropertyChanged with RaisePropertyChanged.

But also thanks to @Sheridan for his advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way of displaying values from the selected item of the `DataGrid`, or in fact any collection control in WPF. That is to use the [`Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem(v=vs.110).aspx). When you set this to true, then you can reference the selected item from that collection using the `/` notation, which means *the current item*. Try something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Employees/Name}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This would display the `Name` property value from the currently selected item in the `DataGrid`. Further information... from the [`Binding.Path` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> When the source is a collection view, the current item can be specified with a slash (/). For example, the clause Path=/ sets the binding to the current item in the view. When the source is a collection, this syntax specifies the current item of the default collection view.
>
> Property names and slashes can be combined to traverse properties that are collections. For example, Path=/Offices/ManagerName specifies the current item of the source collection, which contains an Offices property that is also a collection. Its current item is an object that contains a ManagerName property.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. With this code i can show the Selected value in my Textbox. I want to user to have the possibility to add a new Employee over this screen or update one in the list. For this i made the property SelectedEmployee, that is set to null if the user want to add a new employee

Comment: `SelectedEmployee` has nothing to do with adding a new `Employee`... to do that, you just need to call `Employees.Add(new Employee())`.

Comment: The User has the possibility to enter data into this Textboxes and add a new Employee to the Datagrid. Or he selectes one and change the data of the existing.